# python poetry installing from private repo using pyproject.toml file

Tags: python, python-poetry

hi am trying to to use poetry to install a package with my private repo but it doesn't seem to work.Any idea what am doing wrong?

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "aa"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"
package = {version = "0.1.3", source = "abc"}


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "abc"
url = "url"
default = true

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

I get the error message Because package1 depends on package2 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed
but am able to install the package using pip from my private repo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abc/poetry_test/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clikit/console_application.py", line 131, in run
    status_code = command.handle(parsed_args, io)
  File "/Users/abc/poetry_test/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clikit/api/command/command.py", line 120, in handle
    status_code = self._do_handle(args, io)
  File "/Users/abc/poetry_test/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clikit/api/command/command.py", line 171, in _do_handle
    return getattr(handler, handler_method)(args, io, self)
  File "/Users/abc/poetry_test/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cleo/commands/command.py", line 92, in wrap_handle
    return self.handle()
  File "/Users/abc/poetry_test/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/console/commands/install.py", line 63, in handle
    return_code = installer.run()
  File "/Users/abc/poetry_test/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/installer.py", line 74, in run
    self._do_install(local_repo)
  File "/Users/abc/poetry_test/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/installer.py", line 225, in _do_install
    ops = solver.solve(use_latest=whitelist)
  File "/Users/abc/poetry_test/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py", line 36, in solve
    packages, depths = self._solve(use_latest=use_latest)
  File "/Users/abc/poetry_test/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py", line 190, in _solve
    raise SolverProblemError(e)
```

Comment: well, what's the error message? does it find the repositroy at all? are your credentials not set up? is the package missing?

Comment: @Arne sry about that forgot to add the error msg , i get the error message Because package1 depends on package2 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed. but am able to install the package from using pip from my private repo

Comment: That could be a bunch of things - it might be that the credentials are not set up correctly for poetry, you might have messed up the versioning, or you're using a buggy version of poetry. Maybe if you post the stack trace that poetry gives you gives some info of what it could be, but chances are that it's going to be hard to debug for a person not sitting in your chair.

Comment: @Arne added the stack trace. pip instal package1 --index-url "url" i am able to install using pip but not through poetry. I will check again must have missed something.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure your current poetry env to use the private repo and authorize your poetry against it by setting up your credentials if required:

```
poetry config repositories.abc url
# Setup credentials if needed (e.g: For private pypi repo in gitlab 
# poetry config http-basic.gitlab __token__ YOUR_PRESONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN)
```